# vba cut and past function without any blank row

Tags: excel, vba

Please advise as to what is wrong in my below coding. I am able to cut and past the row but after that i can see blank row in my sheet. How can we automatically adjust the row.

After cut and past there should not be any blank row in original sheet.

```
Dim i As Variant
endrow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To endrow
If ws1.Cells(i, "M").Value = str Then
ws1.Cells(i, "M").EntireRow.Cut Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & LastRow + ).EndxlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next
```

Comment: When you cut and paste, it should remove the row, so your iteration won't work well. Try your loop with `step -1`

Comment: Also swap round your `i` values `For i = endrow To 2 Step -1`. As @Raystafarian suggests, the row gets deleted, meaning the next row (which would become `i` next) actually moves to your current `i` value, meaning it will get missed.

Comment: As everyone else said - you need to work backwards through the sheet. **Also** cutting a value won't delete the cell - it will leave a blank cell (try doing it manually).  After you've made the cut delete the row - `ws1.Cells(i, "M").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim endrow As Long

    'Added this code to get it working on my test file.
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim str As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    str = "DELETE THIS ROW"
    lastrow = 30
    ''''''''''''''''''''''

    endrow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = endrow To 2 Step -1
    If ws1.Cells(i, "M").Value = str Then
        ws1.Cells(i, "M").EntireRow.Cut Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & lastrow).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        ws1.Cells(i, "M").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```